# vb.net - how to automatically close javascript prompt boxes

Tags: html, vb.net, onbeforeunload

How would I go about having my application automatically close an onbeforeunload prompt box that warns you before leaving the page?

Example: http://sharecash.org/download.php?file=234324234324324324 (try leaving or closing the page)

Comment: I hate sites like that.  I'm sure others do too!

Comment: @JonH It is just an example link :) I am not asking anyone to download anything.

Comment: Evan: What i don't understand is, you ask how to close an onbeforeunload prompt box that you've self opened? Why do you use it when you don't want it to be visible?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter The site that the application navigate to is not my site.

Comment: i understand, it's not a WebApplication.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a (freeware) program to handle this sort of thing, its called A Form Filler ( www.aformfiller.com ) - basically all you do is watch for the form to appear and when it appears send the keys strokes.

In this case send a L and an Enter.